# Getting xml parent node tag name with child node value using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I need to transform XML using xslt.

i want to transform a node that has child nodes, to node that his tag name 
is the name of the parent and his value is the value of one of his children.

example:

the given xml:

```
<Parent>
  <ChildA>1</ChildA>
  <ChildB>2</ChildB>
</Parent>
```

the desired xml output:

```
<Parent>2</Parent>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not specifying which child node you are interested in....

Something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="Parent">
  <Parent>
    <xsl:value-of select="ChildB"/>
  </Parent>
</xsl:template>
```

uses the value of the first child node called `ChildB` (if any). This:

```
<xsl:template match="Parent">
  <Parent>
    <xsl:value-of select="*[2]"/>
  </Parent>
</xsl:template>
```

uses the value of the second child node. This:

```
<xsl:template match="Parent">
  <Parent>
    <xsl:value-of select="*[last()]"/>
  </Parent>
</xsl:template>
```

uses the value of the last child node....

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:element name="../node-name()">
 <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:element>
```

Comment: I think you need braces: `name="{../name()}"`